# Update Highchart simple gauge using stomp

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highcharts. I am trying to display a simple gauge which should be updated as and when my server send a new value to the client. I am using stomp over websocket to receive the server updates and I want to update the gauge using the latest value. This isn't happening. The gauge doesn't change. Following is the code. I am sure I am missing something, but not sure what. Any help would be appreciated much.

```
<html>
<head xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<title>Highcharts</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>    
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

   <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
      rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />   
   <script src="js/sockjs-0.3.4.js"></script>
   <script src="js/stomp.js"></script>




</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
    <div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Messages:</h3>
    <ol id="messages"></ol>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var newValue;
    var initialValue = 60;
    console.log("page loaded");


   var chart = {      
      type: 'solidgauge'
   };
   var title = null;

   var pane = {
      center: ['50%', '85%'],
      size: '140%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
         backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
         innerRadius: '60%',
         outerRadius: '100%',
         shape: 'arc'
      }
   };

   var tooltip = {
      enabled: false
   };

   // the value axis
   var yAxis = {
      stops: [
         [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
         [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
         [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
      ],
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickPixelInterval: 400,
      tickWidth: 0,
      title: {
         y: -70
      },
      labels: {
         y: 16
      },
      min: 0,
      max: 200,
      title: {
         text: 'Speed'
      }
   };     

   var plotOptions = {
      solidgauge: {
         dataLabels: {
            y: 5,
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true
         }
      }
   };

   var credits = {
      enabled: false
   };

   var series = [{
      name: 'Speed',
      data: [initialValue],
      dataLabels: {
         format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
         ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
         '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
      },
      tooltip: {
         valueSuffix: ' km/h'
      }
   }];

   var json = {};   
   json.chart = chart; 
   json.title = title;       
   json.pane = pane; 
   json.tooltip = tooltip; 
   json.yAxis = yAxis; 
   json.credits = credits; 
   json.series = series;     
   $('#container-speed').highcharts(json);   


       var socket = new SockJS('/stomp');

       var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

       var message;

       stompClient.connect({ }, function(frame) {
           // subscribe to the /topic/message endpoint
           stompClient.subscribe("/topic/message", function(data) {
               //alert("new value from server = "+data.body);
               message = data.body;
               newValue = JSON.stringify(data.body);
               console.log("data = "+newValue);
           });
       });     


 var chartFunction = function() {
      // Speed
      var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts();
      var point;
      var newVal;
      var inc;

      if (chart) {
          point = chart.series[0].points[0];
          newVal = message;  
          point.update(newVal);
          console.log("newVal = "+ newVal);       
      } 

   };    

  setInterval(chartFunction, 2000);


});
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have your data loaded each 2s? how your console.log looks? Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: I want the gauge to be refreshed once stomp client receives the new updates from server. My console doesn't show any errors; it prints out the new values that keep coming through the websocket; Here's how the console looks :page loaded
stomp.js:130 Opening Web Socket...
stomp.js:130 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:130 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

data = "153"
2showchart:189 newVal = 153
stomp.js:130 <<< MESSAGE
destination:/topic/message
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-0
message-id:v5e2_02p-1
content-length:3

Comment: is your newVal number or string? Because Highcharts accept only numbers

Comment: I am so glad you pointed me to the right direction. It was indeed string; now I changed it to "newVal = parseInt(message);" and the gauge is moving. Thank you!